# Karate: Can we add Karate-Robot to existing project in eclipse

Tags: karate

I have a Karate project for API+UI in Eclipse IDE can i add Karate-robot to the same project to have more scenarios

I gone through the document and download the ZIP and jar and tried to run in command screen and it worked, but i like to try and implement in eclipse IDE existing project.

Is there any sample project in GIT, i tried with karate-robot from karate-1.2.0.RC1 release but its not executing in IDE.

Kindly let me know a way to implement karate-robot in eclipse IDE as we use this IDE for API and UI and Intellij for Performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate Robot is just a Maven library like everything else, refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot#maven

So just adding this to your `pom.xml` or equivalent should just work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-robot</artifactId>
    <version>${karate.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But if you run into further issues, please consider contributing code :)

Comment: Thanks, I added in existing project and it worked for me, but observed slower execution while compared with duration from command screen using ZIP package. Suggestion please

Comment: @Shree here is my suggestion: please help us improve it ! maybe it is using a different JVM, maybe Eclipse UI adds overhead. try running a test from maven via the command line

Comment: Its slower while used in command line for maven project

Comment: @Shree I have nothing more to add